# My materials aren't baking properly

Tags: materials, texture-baking

I'm trying to make a mod for a Unity game and my mesh has very simple materials but when I try to bake them into one they just come out as one flat color

[image]

This is how the model looks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is how the materials look

I followed [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS4rqkqmg7Y) to bake the materials but when I do it the model with the bake (on the right) ends up like this:

[image]

I've been bashing my head against this problem with other options but I can't seem to get it right I truly need help on this if anyone is willing to lend a hand

Comment: Hello, you can't bake Shader to RGB, I guess this is your problem here